# Compiling GDB with TUI on Windows

Tags: compiler-errors, gdb

I use MSYS with the following line:

```
./configure --enable-tui --with-curses --libdir=/
```

and get the following error when using make:

```
checking for library containing waddstr... (cached) no
configure: error: no enhanced curses library found; disable TUI
make[1]: *** [configure-gdb] Error 1
```

I installed mingw32-libncurses (both dev and dll) using the MinGW Installation Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even official build has TUI disabled. Besides it's not that great if you compare it with emacs-gdb mode or eclipse.

Which "MinGW Installation manager" did you use? I strongly suggest this [MSYS2 installer](http://msys2.github.io/). Scratch your existing MSYS and MinGW, if you use the old one, and follow instructions in the link, using `pacman` to install all needed packages.